# How to clean up instances created by SimpleInjector during verification?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, simple-injector

As a part of creating my SimpleInjector container, I've followed recommended practices and called `container.Verify()` to check that my type registrations make sense.

This works well and has caught a number of errors that I've made - but it also creates debris that lingers around afterwards that I'd like to clean up.

One of my classes is a singleton *event hub* that's used to route messages between other transient components; these other components accept the event hub in their constructor, create a subscription to receive the messages they're interested in receiving, then `Dispose()` the subscription when they're finished.

The call to `container.Verify()` creates one of each kind of object, resulting in a number of these otherwise transient instances lingering around because the event hub still knows about their subscriptions.

At the moment I've worked around the problem by manually terminating all subscriptions immediately after the `Verify()` call, before the application starts up. However, this feels like a problem that must be already solved, though I haven't been able to find an answer in the docs, here on Stack Overflow, or by searching.

Perhaps using a scoped lifestyle is the solution? They didn't seem relevant because I'm building a WPF application, but if I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking here!

**Update, 12 Jan** - As requested by @steven, here's some code to demonstrate my issue.

*I tried (and failed) to demonstrate the issue with something that was both compilable and short enough to share inline; instead I'm showing some code excerpts from the actual project. If you want to see the whole thing, the [WordTutor project is on GitHub](https://github.com/theunrepentantgeek/wordtutor).*

At the core of my application I have a singleton `IReduxStore<T>` which both encapsulates application state and acts as a kind of event hub. Other classes subscribe to the store in order to be proactively notified when the application state changes.

Here is `IReduxStore<T>`, pared down to the essentials:

```cs
// IReduxStore.cs
public interface IReduxStore<T>
{
    T State { get; }
    void Dispatch(IReduxMessage message);

    IDisposable SubscribeToReference<V>(
        Func<T, V?> referenceReader,
        Action<V?> whenChanged)
        where V : class, IEquatable<V>?;
}
```

Subscriptions implement `IDisposable` as a convenient and idiomatic way for deterministic cleanup when the subscription is no longer required.

The store is registered as a singleton, bound to a specific type of state:

```cs
// Program.cs
container.RegisterSingleton<
    IReduxStore<WordTutorApplication>,
    ReduxStore<WordTutorApplication>>();
```

The implementation of `IReduxStore<T>` stores all the subscriptions:

```cs
private readonly HashSet<ReduxSubscription<T>> _subscriptions
    = new HashSet<ReduxSubscription<T>>();
```

They're removed from the `HashSet` when disposed.

Many of my ViewModels accept `IReduxStore<WordTutorApplication>` to their constructors so they can subscribe to updates:

```cs
// VocabularyBrowserViewModel.cs
public sealed class VocabularyBrowserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IReduxStore<WordTutorApplication> _store;
    private readonly IDisposable _screenSubscription;
    private readonly IDisposable _vocabularySubscription;

    public VocabularyBrowserViewModel(IReduxStore<WordTutorApplication> store)
    {
        _store = store ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(store));

        // ... elided ...

        _screenSubscription = _store.SubscribeToReference(
            app => app.CurrentScreen as VocabularyBrowserScreen,
            RefreshFromScreen);

        _vocabularySubscription = _store.SubscribeToReference(
            app => app.VocabularySet,
            RefreshFromVocabularySet);

        // ... elided ...
    }

   // ... elided ...
}
```

ViewModels are registered as transient because each window needs a unique instance:

```cs
// Program.cs
var desktopAssembly = typeof(WordTutorWindow).Assembly;
container.Collection.Register<ViewModelBase>(desktopAssembly);
```

The ViewModels release their subscriptions proactively when they are no longer needed:

```cs
// VocabularyBrowserViewModel.cs
private void RefreshFromScreen(VocabularyBrowserScreen? screen)
{
    if (screen == null)
    {
        _screenSubscription.Dispose();
        _vocabularySubscription.Dispose();
        return;
    }

    Selection = screen.Selection;
    Modified = screen.Modified;
}
```

When `Verify()` is called on the SimpleInjector container, an exemplar of every object is created, including the singleton `IReduxStore<T>`. The transient viewmodels (such as `VocabularyBrowserViewModel` shown above) are also created, but those instances remain ***live*** because their subscriptions are still held by the store.

I tried implementing `IDisposable` on the ViewModels, but because their lifestyle is *transient*, the only effect was to generate an additional warning when `Verify()` was called.

**Update II, 12 Jan**:

The workaround I have at the moment is to manually clear all the subscriptions as a part of application startup, after the container has been successfully initialized:

```cs
var store = (ReduxStore<WordTutorApplication>)
    container.GetInstance<IReduxStore<WordTutorApplication>>();
store.ClearSubscriptions();
```

This feels like a nasty hack. First it needs to explicitly cast to the implementation type, then it calls a method that otherwise wouldn't need to exist at all.

Comment: Some code that shows what you're doing inside your transient components to hook onto the event hub, and some code that shows how event hub holds on to the subscriptions would be beneficial to your question.

Comment: @Bevan Your workaround seems fine, given it's executed in composition root. If you don't want to extend the API for this one case, you could use a unit test to kill two birds with one stone. Quoting the [docs](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#verify-the-container-s-configuration): "consider wrapping the Verify call in an #IF DEBUG compiler directive, or run Verify only as part of an unit/integration test. This keeps startup time short, and moves the performance penalty to every first resolve of an individual registration.".

Comment: If you used the [WeakEventManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.weakeventmanager?view=netframework-4.8), the subscriptions wouldn't make the subscribers stay in memory.

Besides that I don't think it's a good approach to influence the lifetime of Views and ViewModels using the IDisposable interface and the RefreshFromScreen callback from the View. 

The ViewModel should not know about the View. Can't you just keep a reference to the active ViewModel and let the others get garbage collected?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider moving the container.Verify() call to a unit test since actually what it's doing is to test whether or not your registrations are correct. It doesn't answer your question but solves your problem.

Comment: You have a design problem which is that you say View Models proactively release their subscriptions when they are not needed, but the situations in which RefreshFromScreen is called do not include all the situations in which the subscriptions are no longer needed but you are not calling RefreshFromScreen in that case. Evidence, the subscriptions triggered by Verify are no longer needed. I subscribe to Victor Ortundo’s comment, alternatively you could use weak references in the hub events that the View Models are subscribing to.

Comment: @BalintPogatsa & @sjb-sbj The ViewModels know nothing about the Views - the `RefreshFromScreen()` callback is refreshing from a *model* class called `Screen` (perhaps there's a naming issue there I need to fix). The only live reference to the viewmodels is the subscription from the central store.

Comment: @sjb-sjb The `RefreshFromScreen()` method is part of the subscription from the central store, so I shouldn't need to call it manually. I think you might be on to something with your comment that it's not handling all the expected situations.

Comment: As @VictorOrtuondo mentions above, I've always done the Verify() as a unit test. Verifying your object graph is complete by actually instantiating everything just does not feel like a production concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `EnableAutoVerification` to false in Simple Injector 5.0 (https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/P_SimpleInjector_ContainerOptions_EnableAutoVerification.htm)